# Elimination of a parameter via Integration

Tags: linear-algebra, integration, multivariable-calculus, linear-transformations

Consider a function $P$ which integrates to unity in full space.
$$
P(a,b,c,d) = \exp\left[a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2\right](a-b)(b-c)(c-d)
$$
I need to eliminate $d$.

One way is to perform a linear transformation in which variables $a,b,c$ can be expressed in terms of $d$ and finally it can be integrated out. This is just a vague idea. I am really not sure if this will work and even if it does, I don't know how to proceed.

Also I would like to know if there is any other way to do this exercise.

Comment: what do you mean `eliminate`? If $P$ is dependent on $d$, how can you remove this except by assuming some relationship $d$ has with the outside world?

Comment: By eliminate I mean 'making Independent'. I want to make P independent of d.

Comment: Its full space. (sorry for incorporating physics terminology)@user251257